# Short story about a pregnant time traveller set in the wild west

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The plot:

Set in 19th century USA, the main character is a man who is a sheriff, but who is dominated by the local bad guys, who at some point have attacked him and dislocated both his arms, rendering him incapable of doing his role. He meets up with a strange pregnant woman from the future who is being pursued by someone or something, and is looking for a safe place in Time to have her baby. She repairs his arms and jumps forward in time to get him a magnum  handgun and ammunition, enabling him to resolve his problem with the bad guys. She has her baby and then leaves.

I thought the title was *Shootout at Dawn* or similar but can't locate it. I don't recall the author or year.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  (Was it in a magazine, an anthology, or was it online?)

Comment: Thank you. I believe it was in an anthology.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This sounds like *[Skirmish on a Summer Morning](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93680)*, a novelette by Bob Shaw, first published in 1976.

Your summary was very accurate, matching the [wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skirmish_on_a_Summer_Morning) very closely:

> Billy Gregg, a middle-aged resident of late 19th-century rural Arizona,
> had tried to defy Josh Potland, a local strongman, which led to his
> being cruelly tortured and left crippled. In the aftermath, he sees no
> alternative but to stay cautiously on his farm, take no further stand
> and draw no further attention to himself. One day he encounters **a
> strange young woman, dressed in curious silver clothing and heavily
> pregnant**, who is hassled by two of Potland's cowboys. Against his
> better judgement, he saves her, in the process wounding one of the
> cowboys, and offers her refuge – of which she is clearly in dire need
> – on his farm.
>
> This draws to him once again the highly unwelcome attention of Potland
> and his gang, who seek revenge and also feel that Gregg is "too old
> for such choice woman-flesh". And even the threat they pose is dwarfed
> by that of the sinister "Hunter", a faceless figure shrouded in a dark
> aura, who relentlessly hunts Morna. If she is to be believed, he was
> sent by ancient enemies who have been fighting Morna's people (whoever
> they might be) for twenty thousand years.
>
> Though highly vulnerable when her time for giving birth arrives, Morna
> is not without resource. She provides Gregg with a gun far superior in
> firepower to anything known in the West (or anywhere in the world of
> the 1880s). If the inscription on the cartridge box is to be believed,
> it comes from 1981, a hundred years in the future. With such a weapon
> in his hand, Gregg just might have a chance to win an epic gunfight
> which would eclipse even the recent one at OK Corral.

Comment: Possibly OP is mixing up the title with [Pistols at Dawn](https://www.paperbackswap.com/Perfect-Timing-Days-Pistols-Dawn/book/0373837038/) which also had a pregnant time-traveler.